# Cleanse List of NCAAB Teams to show without mascot name (more details in description)

Tags: google-sheets, html-lists, vlookup

I have two ImportHTML functions in my sheet, pulling data from different websites. The result is two different (yet very similar) lists of NCAAB teams and their scores. I am trying to vlookup the scores in List 2 based on the school name (without mascot) in List 1. See below:

Example

1. List 1 = Indiana
2. List 2 = Indiana Hoosiers

Example 2

1. List 1 = Duke
2. List 2 = (3) Duke Blue Devils

Here is a link to a google sheets doc where I am working. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nx5RaO5mSKVq_LlWTwrMtuHsqjb69W4_Rzan4Q5HjR0/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you & let me know if more info is needed,

Greg

Comment: Could please explain what data is the one you want to put in column C from list2 sheet?

Comment: Welcome. Would you explain your programming problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Instead of "cleansing" list 2, I just created a reference table linking the name in list 1 to the name in list 2 and doing a vlookup off that.

Thank you.